# Попытки попасть в администраторскую область сайта

Tags: безопасность, веб-программирование

Добрый день, друзья! У меня есть личный сайт, в котором ведется учет всех посещений страниц с различных адресов. Так вот последнее время участились ip-адреса пытающиеся попасть в административную часть и которые очевидно ищут незащищенные скрипты, таблицы стилей и прочее. Привожу пример:

```
http://мой адрес/index.php/admin/css/images/img3.png
http://мой адрес/index.php/trackback/images/img3.png
http://мой адрес/index.php/trackback/images/contact.php
http://мой адрес/index.php/admin/author.php
http://мой адрес/index.php/admin/images/css/function.require-once
```

И тому подобное... Вопросы такие:

1. Кто это делает люди и роботы?
2. Какова вероятность таким макаром найти дыру на сайте?
3. Какие меры рекомендовали бы, по защите от подобного прощупывания сайта?

Comment: Добавлю, пусть и вопрос старый: это боты-сканеры, которые "знают" уязвимости конкретных версий ПО и пытаются их использовать. Достаточно просто не оставлять инсталлеров при установках всяких php-my-admin'ов (а еще лучше ограничивайте доступ к ним по айпи со стороны сервера), и всё будет нормально. Двести строчек 404 GET /phpmyadmin/%итерируемый номер версии%/install.php - это нормально, с этим ничего не сделать, просто на другом конце земного шара резвится какой-то лошпед, который предполагает наличие на сайте того или иного ПО.

Comment: если есть желание, то можно подобным ботам устроить медовую бочку - подсуньте им скрипты, которые они ожидают (поддельные конечно). Можно погуглить и понять, что ожидают от подобных скриптов и сделать фейковый ответ. Я подобным образом когда то останавливал наплыв - боты начинали проверять с вордпресса. Я им подсовывал вордпрес, но старой версии. Они пытались использовать дыру, но там был ответ как от пропатченного. Дальше насиловать сайт они не пытались. Естественно, никакого вордпресса у меня не было:)

Comment: Интересно что они проверяют запросами к png. Наверное закрыт или не закрыт доступ по ip адресу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на какой cms у вас сайт? Проверьте права на файлы и директории, можете сделать доступ к админке только для вашего ip в htaccess, или запретить доступ подозрительным ip. Вероятность найти дыру, зависит от cms, и от программиста который этот сайт делал
как вариант можно еще изменить адрес доступа к админке /admin/

Comment: Сайт на самописном движке, так что стандартные приемы поиска уязвимости тут не помогут им. IP-адреса пытающиеся попасть ко мне в админку самые разные, каждый день какие-то новые адреса, которые повторяют попытки перехода на страницы админки или в модули управления сайтом. В любом случае спасибо за ответы, буду принимать соответствующие меры от злоумышленников.